# How to block all writes and allow only reads in redis server?

Tags: memory-management, redis

I have an use case where I need to put restriction on **used_memory_rss** usage to ensure redis uses the RAM well within the boundary.

In the situations when the RSS of redis reaches the threshold it is expected that redis should not accept any new DB writes whereas it should accept DB reads.

How can we achieve this? Could someone please provide some insights here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maxmemory` configuration to set a memory usage limit, and set the `maxmemory-policy` configuration to **noeviction**.

With the above configuration, when memory usage reaches the limit, Redis will only accepts read operation, and returns error for write operation.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
maxmemory seems to put the restriction only on the data that redis stores. It doesn't consider RSS memory into consideration. 
For example, consider a system of 32GB RAM. maxmemory is set to 28.28GB. But when I execute a top command on linux, I could see the actual redis memory usage is 30.31 GB(which is a RSS memory) Now in the case where maxmemory is not reached and the rss reaches towards physical RAM size, OS will kill redis. Ideally this shouldn't happen for me.
# Memory
used_memory_human:28.28G
used_memory_rss_human:30.31G
maxmemory_human:28.28G

Comment: If you only have 32 GB, you should set maxmemroy to 28.28 GB. That's too much, instead, it should be much safer to set mamemory to about 20G. Also if you want to do persistence, you should set maxmemory to be less than 16G.

Comment: This particular Linux instance is completely dedicated to redis server. If I set the limit to 20 GB, will it be an optimized memory setting? Let's say RSS for redis reached around 23-24 GB then I will end up wasting the memory resource. Your thoughts?